# How to adjust game screen for different devices?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made small 2d game in Unity and it is working fine withi the Unity screen. But when I tested on my android phone the game screen got bigger.

So how can I adjust my game screen? I'm using C# and am completely new to Unity.

Comment: well, first of all, I would like to know what you are doing to make the elements on the screen. are you using a onGUI() methord to show the components or are you using GameObjects?

Comment: Just a heads-up, the [unity] tag is not for the game engine. Please use the [unity3d] tag instead to get the proper attention. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the [screen resolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) to the currently active resolution.

```
Screen.SetResolution (Screen.width, Screen.height, true);
```

Comment: I tried but my GameObject are still clipped as same as before